# Vuevalidate optional validator is not working if you made it optional

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

Greetings I have project on vuejs3 and using vuelidate as validator library. I have form to validate users password. First user must enter tmp password send by server then new password.
Check is made if user entered correct tmp password or not.

I want validator what only works if it have some values(password input is not empty). Currently it launches if password field is empty. And as you expect it throws error on back-end because to end-point was passed String with null.(As back-end I am using C# mvc)

Validator itself

```
import userService from '@/services/user-service';
import { helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators';
const { withAsync } = helpers;

const isPasswordCorrect = helpers.withMessage(
    () => 'The requested password does not belong to this user',
    withAsync(async (value: string) => {
        return await userService.isPasswordCorrect(value); // call to end-point to check if password is correct
    })
);

export { isPasswordCorrect };
```

What I tried to write optional validator as shown in docs [click](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/custom_validators.html#optional-validator) but it does not work. When I press btn to validate form it does nothing. Works as if there was no validator at all.

```
import userService from '@/services/user-service';
import { helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators';
const { withAsync } = helpers;

const isPasswordCorrect = (value: string) => !helpers.req(value) || helpers.withMessage(
    () => 'The requested password does not belong to this user',
    withAsync(async (value: string) => {
        return await userService.isPasswordCorrect(value);
    })
);

export { isPasswordCorrect };
```

So any ideas how to write custom validator what is not "triggered" with empty value?